# Chrome Extension "Go to Home"

Tags: google-chrome-extension, kiosk-mode

I have to show a web project through a touch screen using Chrome in fullscreen and in Kiosk Mode.

People will be able to navigate a website in all its pages also pointing to external links. Since I don't want people to use a keyboard, I'd like to add a sticky button that points back to the home of the project and that is present in ALL the webpages that people open.

Can I do it with a Chrome Extension?

Do you know any existing solution that could solve my problem?

Many thanks! <3

Comment: An extension can add such button into every page by using its *content script* and standard JavaScript+DOM methods. However, if you're looking for an existing extension, StackOverflow is the wrong place.

Comment: There are  many varieties of kiosk software on the market that do exactly what you're looking for (lock down Chrome in full screen mode).  All of them likely solve your issues. Full disclosure: I work for a company that makes one of them.